# Compare the object fields within array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, object

Compare the age of the objects in an array and keep only the one with the highest age. I've gone through the solution which uses reduce function, but is there any other optimal way other than using reduce?
I am new to javascript, and still learning the concepts.

```
array: [ { "name": "sample", "age": 22 },{ "name": "sample2", "age": 42 }]
```

Comment: please add your approach. what other way are you thinking of?

Comment: sort the array based in ascending/descending order based on age, then taking the correct object

Comment: optimal?  reduce is O(n) and there is not a more efficient order for that. Doing a loop may be slightly faster or slower. There are a lot of ways to iterate an array: for loop, while loop, forEach, map, reduce, filter, etc.

Comment: @utSharma sorting is definitely not an optimal solution, as OP requested. O(n * log n).

Comment: The issue is, I am already using forEach, and inside that I've to add a logic to find the object with highest age, so I am not sure if having reduce inside forEach is a good option or not?

Comment: what if you have more than one object with same value?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with sort:

```js
const array = [ { "name": "sample", "age": 22 },{ "name": "sample2", "age": 42 }]

const max = array.sort((a, b) => {
  return b.age - a.age
})[0]

console.log([max])
```